# How to redirect to a sub-domain after login, and use different layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When someone creates a account and signs in, I want them to redirect to their custom subdomain that they filled out during registration.

All users still have to be redirected to their dashboard page.

```
some_sub_domain.example.com/dashboard/index
```

1. When they are on their subdomain now, will my links continue to work or do I have to fix them somehow?  (assume I am generating the links using the helpers).
2. Now once they are signed in, I'm thinking of creating a controller class that inherits the ApplicationController, so I can then override the default layout.

   class MemberControllerBase < ApplicationController
    override default layout here
   end

**How can I explicitly set the layout?**
Also, is it possible to change the default location of the views, so I don't mix the views for the websites pages and the pages for when the user is signed in?

Answer (score 1):

### Redirecting

After successful sign in, you can do

```
host_with_subdomain = '<your subdomain>' + request.host
redirect_to url_for(:controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'index', :host => host_with_subdomain)
```

### Links

Links should work if you use helpers.

### Layouts

For example you can do

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  layout "inventory"
  #...
end
```

You can read more about using layouts from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 1):

For every action or controller you can set layout.
For subdomain app
I have similar application you can [refer code](https://github.com/iparam/samay) it might help you.